# docker: Error response from daemon: error setting label on mount source '/': SELinux relabeling of / is not allowed

Tags: docker

I am using this command to install harbor 2.0.2 in Fedora 32:

```
wget -c https://github.com/goharbor/harbor/releases/download/v2.0.2/harbor-offline-installer-v2.0.2.tgz
tar -zxvf harbor-offline-installer-v2.0.2.tgz
sudo ./install.sh
```

but it show me this:

```
[dolphin@localhost harbor]$ sudo ./install.sh
[sudo] password for dolphin: 

[Step 0]: checking if docker is installed ...

Note: docker version: 19.03.11

[Step 1]: checking docker-compose is installed ...

Note: docker-compose version: 1.25.4

[Step 2]: loading Harbor images ...
Loaded image: goharbor/prepare:v2.0.2
Loaded image: goharbor/harbor-jobservice:v2.0.2
Loaded image: goharbor/harbor-registryctl:v2.0.2
Loaded image: goharbor/registry-photon:v2.0.2
Loaded image: goharbor/harbor-core:v2.0.2
Loaded image: goharbor/notary-signer-photon:v2.0.2
Loaded image: goharbor/clair-photon:v2.0.2
Loaded image: goharbor/trivy-adapter-photon:v2.0.2
Loaded image: goharbor/harbor-log:v2.0.2
Loaded image: goharbor/nginx-photon:v2.0.2
Loaded image: goharbor/clair-adapter-photon:v2.0.2
Loaded image: goharbor/chartmuseum-photon:v2.0.2
Loaded image: goharbor/harbor-portal:v2.0.2
Loaded image: goharbor/harbor-db:v2.0.2
Loaded image: goharbor/redis-photon:v2.0.2
Loaded image: goharbor/notary-server-photon:v2.0.2


[Step 3]: preparing environment ...

[Step 4]: preparing harbor configs ...
prepare base dir is set to /home/dolphin/apps/harbor
docker: Error response from daemon: error setting label on mount source '/': SELinux relabeling of / is not allowed.
```

I am searching for github issue but still do not understand what cause this install failure and how to fix this? I try to close selinux using `sudo setenforce 0` but this error still exists.